# Select all Checkboxes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

HI,

I have an HTML which has several a list of items with a checkbox (these are placed in a table). Each row in the table has the following coloumn:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='Events[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='Events[]' value='2'>
etc
```

I would like to have make a link names "select all" that when clicked will select all the items.

I am using the following JS, but it is not working.

```
    function SelectAll(form)
    {
        for(var i in form.Events.childNodes)
            if(form.Events.childNodes[i].type == "checkbox")
                form.Events.childNodes[i].checked = true;
    }
```

Comment: Might not be relevant but I've never seen names in HTML with square brackets is that definitely correct?

Comment: @Martin Smith: Yes, it is. Adding the square brackets there will tell some server-side languages like PHP that `Events` is coming in as an array of checked values, not a scalar value.

Answer (score 5):

The `name` of your input is `Events[]`, so `form.Events` wouldn't find it

Because square brackets don't fit in JavaScript `o.p` property access shortcut, you would have to use the explicit string-based notation to get them:

```
var inputs= form.elements['Events[]'];
```

the `form.elements` collection (and the form collection itself—`form['Events[]']`—which is a non-standardised shortcut to the same thing but with more chance of name clashes) is a bit old-school and has some disadvantages like returning a single element instead of a list when there's only one element. You'd probably be better off using `getElementsByName`:

```
var inputs= form.getElementsByName('Events[]');
```

either way, follow up with:

```
for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;)
    inputs.checked= true;
```

Never use `for...in` to iterate an Array or array-like sequence. It doesn't do what you think at all. Stick to the old-school indexed loop.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go this should work

```
<input class="Events" type='checkbox' name='Events[]' value='1'>
<input class="Events" type='checkbox' name='Events[]' value='2'>


function SelectAll(form) {
  for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i ++) {
     if (form.elements[i].type == "checkbox" && form.elements[i].className="Events") {
        form.elements[i].checked = true;
     }
  }
)
```

Comment: You typed an extra = in the assignment statement ;)

Comment: because im not sure about the name of the element. Never used an array with the selector for form.[ElementName].  For Instance Im not sure what form.Events would actually do.  But I know the class will work.

Answer (score 2):

That will only work for checkboxes that are *directly* in the `<form>` tag, and not nested inside any other tags.

The simplest way to do this is to use jQuery:

```
$(':checkbox', form).attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: @Ahmet: He can then use it elsewhere and probably make the rest of his code far simpler.